# Including satchmo-livesettings in main django-admin site

Tags: python, django, django-admin, satchmo

I plan to use the sachmo-livesettings module in my django application (not using or related to satchmo). In the satchmo store the livesettings are visible on the main django-admin site. When adding livesettings to my app, though I can access them directly using a dedicated url (e.g. ../settings) I don't manage to make them visible on the main django admin site in the menu on the right side. Do you have any ideas how to include a livesettings overview on the admin site?

There is not much documentation on how to use livesettings, do you have any links to documents about satchmo-livesettings and django-admin. I'm particularly interested on how to add things on the right side (where normally the history of changed model objects is displayed).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with the satchmo specific bits, but generally the way you handle this kind of thing in Django is by [overriding admin templates](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates) and creating your own /admin/ urls/views.